# *Form is not working in script

Tags: formatting, scripting

I want to generate code with a script. But functions as `CForm`, `FortranForm` and `TeXForm` does not seem to work when running code from script file.

Example:

```
(* test.m *) 
Print[ CForm[1+2x+3x^2] ];
```

In command line

```
$ MathKernel -script test.m
CForm[1 + 2*x + 3*x^2]
```

I would expect

```
$ MathKernel -script test.m
1 + 2*x + 3*Power(x,2)
```

Comment: What happens if you remove the `Print` wrapper?

Comment: @MarcoB Then there is no output to the command line. But I also tried saving it to the file using `Save` command and it does not work either.

Comment: This worked for me:  `Put[ CForm[ 1+2x+3x^2 ], "output.txt" ]`

Comment: @Louis Great!, It works. And after re-reading documentation of `Put` and `Save` it is clear to me. But why `Print` behaves differently in a script and in a notebook is still a mystery to me.